# Is there a way to solve my problem of pop up?

Tags: javascript

I am a little new to javascript programming. I am doing a notification management application. I'm trying  to make a pop up like the `facebook` notifications. when I click on the icon it appears, when i click in the form of the pop up it does not disappear, which is normal, when i click anywhere on the screen the pop up disappears and that's good too. When i put text in my pop up and when I click it does not disappear, which is still normal, but when i create a table or a form as soon as i click to grab something it disappears. Help me please. here is my code.

```js
function notification() {
  document.getElementById("forme").style.display = "block";
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target == forme || e.target == bouton) {
    document.getElementById("forme").style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("forme").style.display = "none"; 
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="icone">
        <span>
          <a href="#"><img src="bell.png" width="40px" height="40px" id="bouton" onclick="notification()"></a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="forme" class="popup">
    <form action="index.php">
      <input type="text" name="">
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? It wasnt 100% clear in the question

Comment: do you need just the standard modal functionality in bootstrap? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ ex: https://jsfiddle.net/3q8do40c/1/

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, the condition `e.target == forme` in the if statement will not be met becacue it is the id of the div element. If you add an id to the input element and include it in the conditions of your if statement, the input will stay open.

Also, if you would like to keep the popup open when selecting other items, you can add the ids of the items to your if statement.

```js
function notification() {
  document.getElementById("forme").style.display = "block";
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if ( e.target == bouton || e.target == formeInput) {
    document.getElementById("forme").style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("forme").style.display = "none"; 
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="icone">
        <span>
          <a href="#"><img src="bell.png" width="40px" height="40px" id="bouton" onclick="notification()"></a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="forme"  class="popup">
    <form action="index.php">
      <input id="formeInput" type="text" name="">
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

With regards to being able to click on a pop-up table filled with links from an SQL database, and being able to keep the table open, as @Robb mentioned in the comments to your question, I do recommend using Bootstrap's modal since you are already using Bootstrap. This would provide a more easily reusable solution with the same functionality.

If you would still like a solution that does not involve the use of Bootstrap's modal, you can target the table's Id through the use of sevaral `.parentElement` properties together following `e.target`in your if statement. In the same if statement, you can use ".classList.contains("insert-class-for-links")" to know when the links on the table are being clicked.

The following is code that you can use for this solution:

```js
function notification() {
  document.getElementById("forme").style.display = "block";
}

document.onclick = function(e) {
if(e.target != null && e.target.parentElement != null &&
e.target.parentElement.parentElement != null

&&
e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement != null

)

{


  if ( e.target == bouton|| e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement == pTable
  ||
  e.target.classList.contains("aClass")
  ) {
    document.getElementById("forme").style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("forme").style.display = "none"; 
  }
  
  
}

else{

    document.getElementById("forme").style.display = "none"; 


}



}
```

```css
.aClass

{

background-color:blue;
}

.tableClass

{
  background-color:green;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="icone">
        <span>
          <a href="#"><img src="bell.png" width="40px" height="40px" id="bouton" onclick="notification()"></a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="forme"  class="popup">
   
   <!--
   <form action="index.php">
      <input id="formeInput" type="text" name="">
    </form>
    -->
    
    <div  >






</br>


<table id="pTable" class = "tableClass">
        <tr>
            <td><a class="aClass"  href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a></td>
            <td><a class="aClass" href="#">content</a>></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: even putting an id to the form and including it in the if condition of the javascript code does not solve the problem.

Comment: Did you add the id to the input element? Adding the id to the form will not keep the input box open either.

Comment: thank you it works.
what worries me is that I will display in this pop up the result of a sql query. the result will be displayed in a table. this table I have to make the lines clickable. for not having the same problem I have to put the id in the table tag?

Comment: Yes Part of the solution would entail putting the id in the table element. If you do that, you would have to edit the if statement used to ascertain where e.target is pointing. e.target would not point to the table id just by using e.target == id , but it can point directly to the links on the table and it can point to the table id using  several .parentElement properties together (In this case). I have updated my answer to provide a solution for this.

Comment: Also, as @Robb pointed out in the comments to your question, since you are already using Bootstrap, an alternative and more easily reusable solution would be to add the table to a modal, which would provide the same functionality as the popup.